# UITableView will crash the app if It tries to display an array that has more than 13 elements

Tags: swift, uitableview, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

So I'm using Swift 3.

The app works fine if I make `limit` equals 13 or less elements. But if I let it reads more than 13 it crashes.

Here is the code:

```
var CoolArray = [Event]()
var num = 0

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return CoolArray.count
}

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("Displaying the outputs using array[indexPath.row]")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

    let oneRow = CoolArray[indexPath.row] 
    cell.name.text = oneRow.name
   return cell
}

var CoolArray = [Event]()
var num = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {

 let request =
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/somefacebookpag/events",
                          parameters: ["fields": "name,cover,place,start_time,end_time,description, owner",
                                       "limit":"10", ],
                          httpMethod: "GET")
      request?.start { ( connection, result, error) in

      if let array = result as? [String : AnyObject]{
            if let fbData = array["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]       {
                print("working")
                for event in fbData {
                    if let nameOfEvent = event["name"] as? String,
                    {
                        print("Read array \(self.num)")
                        self.num += 1
                        let anotherOne = Event(name: nameOfEvent)

                        self.CoolArray.append(anotherOne)

                    }

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps. Commenting the code in viewDidLoad makes it work properly

Comment: That might be the limit of FaceBook put on it

Comment: @MNM, I just tried it by setting the limit to 25 and printing the output fetched from Facebook to the console and it displayed 25 results

Comment: It may then be an out of memory issue. What does your crash say